# How to set Azure sensitivity label for word document through vba

Tags: vba, azure, ms-word

Trying to add azure sensitivity label through vba code for word document.

Not sure about parameters and syntax.
How do I get the label id and info?

```
Function ExportWordDocument()
    
    Dim objword,wshshell,objdoc,objselection,objshape,i
    Set objword=createobject("word.application")
    
    objword.Visible=True
    objword.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Set objdoc=objword.Documents.Add()
    Set objselection=objword.Selection
    Set objshape=objdoc.Shapes
    Dim objscreenshotsfolder,objscreenshot
    objword.ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties.Add "MSIP_Label_xxxxxx_Enabled", True,4,"Confidentail", "True"
    objscreenshotsfolder=Environment.Value("respath")
    For i = Environment.value("snapshotNoNext") To Environment.value("snapshotno") Step 1
        objscreenshot="Screenshot_"&i&".bmp"
        objselection.TypeText objscreenshot
        objselection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(objscreenshotsfolder&"\"&objscreenshot)
    Next

    objword.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 Environment.Value("respath")&"\"&Environment.value("testCaseId")&"_screenshots.doc"
    objword.Quit
    Set objword =Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Added the code, Is there any way to use save method with given path. I believe, it causes the issue while saving as another document